# How to get a inverse-cumulative sum of a vector in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to get a inverse-cumulative sum of a symbolic vector?

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.placeholder('float32', [None])
output = some_function(input)
```

For example

**Input**

```
input = [1,2,3,4]
```

**Output**

```
`output` = [1+2+3+4, 2+3+4, 3+4, 4] = [10, 9, 7, 4]
```

Comment: this resembles the matrix product `[1,2,3,4]*[1 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 1 1 1 0; 1 1 1 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.cumsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/scan#cumsum):

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.placeholder('float32', [None])
output = tf.cumsum(input, reverse=True)
```